# Difference in estimates from regression on individual and aggregated data

Tags: regression, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I am trying to estimate a two-way fixed effects model:

$$
y_{jt} = \alpha_j+\lambda_t+\tau D_{jt}+e_{jt}
$$

Let's say $j$ is job, $t$ is time, $D_{jt}$ is some time-varying job characteristic, and $y_{jt}$ is an outcome. Now suppose I have a repeated cross-sectional data at an employee level $i$. I don't have any interesting time-varying variables at the employee level that I can add to the above model. I see two ways of estimating the above the regression:

- Aggregate the data at $j$ and $t$ level, and estimate a two-way within estimate of $\tau$. This is possible since I can identify $\tau$ as $D_{jt}$ varies at the job level.
- Use the individual data and estimate:

$$
y_{ijt} = \alpha_j+\lambda_t+\tau D_{ijt}+e_{ijt}
$$

I want to understand:

- If this would lead to different estimates of $\tau$?
- If so, what factors generally lead to the difference?

Comment: One obvious difference is that aggregating data is a *smoothing* transformation which reduces variability.

Comment: Should that effect the estimate of $\tau$ or only its standard error?

Comment: Just so I am clear, at what *level* is the treatment?

Comment: @ThomasBilach $D_{jt}$ varies at the job $j$ level and over time $t$.

Comment: And are these just different samples of employees at the same job $j$ and at each time period $t$?